# Let $E:y^2=x^3+x$ be an elliptic curve.$(x,y)→(-x,iy)$ goes to both $(x,y)→(-x,2y)$, $(x,y)→(-x,3y)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $E:y^2=x^3+x$ be an elliptic curve. There is natural injection $End(E)→End( \tilde{E})$, which sends $\phi$ to it's reduction by $mod5$ (isogeny made by reduction of coefficients). But $(x,y)→(-x,iy)$ goes to $(x,y)→(-x,2y)$, $(x,y)→(-x,3y)$, does't this show the correspondence $End(E)→End( \tilde{E})$ is not well defined ?

Where am I missing ?

Comment: Please define all objects in order, do not introduce things like $\bar E$ without telling us what it is (best before use, this should be easy compared with the level of the question). My eye compiles the text further and sees that $\phi$... What is $\phi$. Please understand that a "good question" in spirit of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question wants a question where you show context, best explaining what you tried and where you get stuck, a question with well defined objects. What is the definition field for $E$? What means "$\phi$ goes to something"?

Comment: Asking one clear question in a clear framework would make answering much easier. Over $\Bbb Q(i)$, $i=\sqrt{-1}$, there are two roots of $X^2+1=0$. They are $\pm i$. Over $\Bbb F_5$ there are also two roots of the "same" polynomial, $\pm 2$. Now you want someting with an "injection" (in which category do we work, sets and morphisms, or projective schemes over a fixed / or movingbase field?! ...) this is hard to digest. There's nothing well defined so far when the question comes: "*does't this show the correspondence ... is not well defined ?*" And just one question, please. No "*Where...?*

Comment: Short answer: $(x,y) \longmapsto (-x,iy)$ is an endomorphism of $E_K$, with $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$. So to make it act on a reduction of $E$, you need to specify modulo which maximal ideal *of $O_K$* you reduce.

Comment: @Aphelli Otherwise is it allowed to reduce $E/\Bbb{Z}[i]$ modulo $5$? I mean with $R=\Bbb{Z}[i][x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x), R/(5)\cong R/(2+i)\times R/(2-i)$ and similarly for the $O_X$ sheaf.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, of course we can formally reduce $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ mod $5$ in this way – it just becomes a *relative* elliptic curve $E \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{F}_5^2}$, over a base ring which is a product of two fields instead of a field.

Comment: I think that what the others said can also be reformulated as follows. There are two automorphisms $\phi_1:(x,y)\mapsto (-x,iy)$ and $\phi_2:(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-iy)$. When you switch to the $\pmod 5$ universe, one becomes $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,2y)$ and the other $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,3y)$. But we cannot tell which is which unless we give a precise meaning to $i$ in $\Bbb{F}_5$.